# Facebook Android SDK : Issue

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated Facebook sdk with my Android app.. After successfull login insted of **Allow** button **Install** is shown..Anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: If you posted some code you would have better chance of getting helpful answer...

Comment: yes first time it show app to install for the key which is new for your facebook account so just install it

Comment: But it should show an allow page.right?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to (authorize)install the app in order to get(give in this case) the access permissions (allow).